# Capturing number after p value

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I have in R strings like this;

```
data_have="0.50 (0.11-1.65, p=0.214)"
```

**data_want=0.214**

I've tried this but it's not what I need :

```
gsub(".*\\b(*p)", "\\1", varname$ratio')
```

Anyone have an idea how to select that number?
also the `)` must be the end of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sub` :

```
sub(".*p=(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\)$", "\\1", data_have)
#[1] "0.214"
```

Maybe add `as.numeric` to convert the above to a number.

Comment: Thanks Ronak, this work like charm, may i ask you how to add a condition if p> or p< or p= ? ( i fixed it with the dot, but in c ase of using the pipe operator ? thanks

Comment: probably should work like this `sub(".*p[=<>](\\d+\\.\\d+)\\)$", "\\1", data_have)`

Answer (score 1):

This will get everything between the `p=` and the `)` at the end of the string: `p=(.*)\\)$`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `gsub`

```
gsub(".*p=|\\)", "", data_have)
#[1] "0.214"
```